# Memory leak with my C# code. Possible solution?

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been getting into C# just a few weeks ago and mainly tried to find my way with console-based applications as an entry point. I didn't seem to face any issues in regards to performance or memory leaks in any way. However, with my current project in the works, I have been facing quite an effective and infuriating example of what memory leaks might look like. The code can be seen below:

```
    public Button button1,button2,button3;
    public Form1()
    {
        this.Text = "Minimal Multimedia Timer";
        this.Height = 210;
        this.Width = 410;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;

        Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.Location = new Point (15, 15);
        label1.Text = "Maximum Resolution:\n0.5ms";
        label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 32);
        label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Underline);
        this.Controls.Add(label1);

        Label label2 = new Label();
        label2.Location = new Point (15, 70);
        label2.Text = "Default Resolution:\n15.625 - 1.0ms";
        label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 32);
        label2.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Underline);
        this.Controls.Add(label2);

        button1 = new Button();
        button1.Size = new Size(70, 30);
        button1.Location = new Point(20, 135);
        button1.Text = "Maximum";
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

        button2 = new Button();
        button2.Size = new Size(70, 30);
        button2.Location = new Point(165, 135);
        button2.Text = "Default";
        this.Controls.Add(button2);
        button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);

        button3 = new Button();
        button3.Size = new Size(70, 30);
        button3.Location = new Point(310, 135);
        button3.Text = "Close";
        this.Controls.Add(button3);
        button3.Click += new EventHandler(button3_Click);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    uint CurrentResolution = 0;
    uint MaximumResolution = 0;
    uint DesiredResolution = MaximumResolution;
    bool SetResolution = true;
    NtSetTimerResolution(DesiredResolution, SetResolution, out CurrentResolution);
    string title = "Timer Set";
    string message = "The timer has been set to the lowest possible parameter:\n" + (CurrentResolution * 0.0001) + "ms.";
    MessageBox.Show(message, title);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
    
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    uint CurrentResolution = 0;
    uint MaximumResolution = 156250;
    uint DesiredResolution = MaximumResolution;
    bool SetResolution = true;
    NtSetTimerResolution(DesiredResolution, SetResolution, out CurrentResolution);
    string title = "Timer Set";
    string message = "The timer has been set back to its default:\n" + (CurrentResolution * 0.0001) + "ms.";
    MessageBox.Show(message, title);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    this.Close();
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Is there a proper way that can easily be implemented into this code that answers my question and fixes my problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The committed memory at start is 58,212, the working set is 17,820, shareable is 17,820 and private is 2,836 at startup. After repeatedly calling for actions, the committed memory becomes 58,780, the working set 22,160, the shareable 18,692 and private rises to 3,468. It seems like my worries were somewhat overblown, but this still confuses me.

Comment: `quite an effective and infuriating example of what memory leaks might look like` - and what would that be?

Comment: Simply pressing one of the first two buttons raises the memory utilization by a few percentages, compared to the compiled RAM utilization at the start, which would be 1.8 megabytes (if compiled with C# Framework 3.5).

Comment: Instead of using a sleep for blocking try a WaitOne : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0.  You do not need the sleep in the methods.  The sleep (or waitone) should just be at the end of MAIN.  When the form closes you do not want the form to close so use the form_closing event.  See my code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net?force_isolation=true.  Setting e.Cancel = true; keep the form running after the exit.

Comment: Doesn't that directly call sleep as well?

Comment: @GSerg I guess. So this means that, essentially, I should just leave it be?

Comment: @Mephres Y​e​s.

Comment: I see. It's just unlucky to see because I want this application to be as lightweight as possible in every regard.

Comment: It already requires the (huge) .NET Framework.

Comment: @GSerg : A form has a built in block in the constructor so no sleep (waitone are needed).  The OP can decide for himself if he wants to prevent the form from closing by capturing the exit event.

Comment: I would highly recommend using a memory profiler for any kind of memory debugging. It should be able to 1. Force garbage collection, 2. Show snapshot of memory, 3. Compare snapshots. Some can also hint at common problems, like event handlers that are never unregistered. Just having memory usage increase does not necessarily indicate a problem.